# Shared_ptr на объект(в свойствах класса), владеющий данным объектом

Tags: c++

Если в виде кода:

```
class clB;
class clA
{
    clB obj;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<clA> SHP_clA;

class clB
{
    SHP_clA pointerA;
};
```

Такая конструкция будет нормально работать? Какие проблемы могут возникнуть при использовании?

PS. У меня определения этих двух классов в разных файлах *.h (реализация методов в отдельных *.срр) как мне их правильно пристыковать друг к другу? Сейчас выдает ошибку в файле класса `clA`:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'obj'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Вы бы код поправили, а? А то у вас вначале `class B`, потом какой-то `clB`, потом упоминание идентификатора `objB`, которого в исходнике нет... дайте минимальный пример (но точный!), воспроизводящий проблему. Пока я вижу главную неприятность в том, что вы поле типа `B` объявляете в `A`, но этот `B` - неполный тип. Так что можно объявлять только ссылку/указатель на `B`...

Comment: По PS: В коде нет символа `objB` так что что это за ошибка можно только гадать.

Comment: @Dmitry, Harry уже написал:
"..вы поле типа B объявляете в A, но этот B - неполный тип. Так что можно объявлять только ссылку/указатель на B"
clB - неполный тип там где Вы пытаетесь объявить поле obj в классе clA

Comment: @tonal понял, поэксперементирую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы возможны. Например попытка удаления экземпляра `clA` при срабатывании деструктора экземпляра `clB`, который вызовется из деструктора `clA`.
Совершенно неясно зачем в данном случае использовать `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: А если использовать обычный указатель: `clA * pointerA;`?

Comment: Тогда этой проблемы не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема у вас -

```
class clB;     // Неполное объявление (компилятор знает только
               // о существовании такого класса, но что внутри - не представляет)
class clA
{
    clB obj;   // Вы пытаетесь создать **объект** класса, о котором
               // ничего неизвестно. В частности - сколько памяти для него выделить
               // (был бы указатель - понятно, все они одинаковы... а так?)
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<clA> SHP_clA;

class clB
{
    SHP_clA pointerA;   // Совершенно не возбраняется, тут можно даже сам
                        // объект - к этому моменту компилятор знает все
                        // о класса clA
};
```

Лучше вам переписать вот так:

```
class clB;
typedef std::shared_ptr<clB> SHP_clB;

class clA
{
    SHP_clB pointerB;
    //clB obj;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял.